# Motorola MB8611 Cable Modem and Google Nest WiFi router do not smoothly connect on power-on

Tags: wireless-networking, router, cable-modem, google-wifi

I have the following setup in my home network:

- **Service Provider**: Cox
- **Cable Modem**: Motorola DOCSIS 3.1 MB8611-30
- **WiFi Router**: Google Nest

This system occasionally goes down for different reasons.

Today, it was something on Cox's end. They did some sort of refresh thing. I turned the modem off and unplugged the router, disconnected the coax cable, reconnected after 10 seconds, then started connecting things again

A week ago, it was a return from a long trip. I'd turned everything off to save on power.

Both times, turning the power on, first on the cable modem, I waited for the "Online" light to come on and turn solid blue. The ethernet cable between the modem and router was already plugged in, as per Motorola's instructions. Then I plugged the router power in.

No Internet.

The Motorola instructions only say to wait for the Online light to come on, but it seems to me that this is insufficient. If I wait 10 minutes after the light comes on before turning on the router, then I'm okay. But that's not what [the manual](https://motorolacable.com/documents/MB8611-QuickStart.pdf) says and it's VERY annoying. I can live with it but it's not a good thing.

Has anyone else experienced this issue with this equipment set, and can anyone explain what is going on here? Does the fault lie with Motorola or Google?

Comment: Is the Motorola DOCSIS 3.1 MB8611-30 modem set to bridge mode? It seems to me that there might be a DHCP/NAT conflict between the modem and the Google Nest. Especially if they both are set to manage the same IP range.

Comment: I don’t think that’s the issue. The modem doesn’t manage IP at all, it just has an Ethernet Jack that you can connect to a router. Also, the problem is only with initialization of the router with the modem. If you wait long enough (whatever long enough is, that’s the frustrating part, you can’t tell by the lights on the modem) then the system works fine until it is next shut down.

Comment: Okay, is the Ethernet port on the modem connected to the WAN port on the router? I mean that is a very basic thing that should be done, but always worth asking.